# Update data in MongoDB with Moongoose and MEAN Stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose data like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e394cacaa6512ed00e8d83"),
    "RoleName" : "Manager",
    "UIList" : [ 
        {
            "Edit" : false,
            "View" : false,
            "UiName" : "ElevatorMapping"
        }, 
        {
            "Edit" : false,
            "View" : false,
            "UiName" : "ElevatorAssumptions"
        }, 
        {
            "Edit" : false,
            "View" : false,
            "UiName" : "ManageUnits"
        }, 
        {
            "Edit" : false,
            "View" : false,
            "UiName" : "ManageBuildings"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0,
    "Description" : "fd",
    "IsActive" : true
}
```

Now I want to update UILIST inside UIname:"ElevatorMapping"&"Elevator Assumptions"  View and Edit as True. How to write query for this? I have tried something like below.

Here is my Controller page.

```
 $http.put('/ViewEditupdate/' + id +'/' + uiname + '/' + view + '/' + edit).then(function (response) {

                    refresh();
                })
```

Here id value is taken correctly but the Edit view UI names are not taken. Edit , view name are taken as undefined.

My server.js code

```
app.put('/ViewEditupdate/:id/:uiname/:view/:edit', RoleEntrypath.RoleViewEditupdate);
```

my Schema code

```
    newRole.update({ "UIList.UiName": "ManageRole" }, { "$push": { "UIList.$.View": "true", "UIList.$.Edit": "true" } },
   function (err, doc) {

        res.json(doc);
    }
    );
```

Can anyone give the solution?

Comment: It's very difficult to follow up with your question. Why don't you try to put it in simpler terms?

Comment: HI ankit, I have updated my question

Comment: Can you print all the params values inside your put API? First, let's find out whether you are receiving right values or not. If you are receiving right values then the problem could be with `update` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already updated by using this query.

```
 newRole.update
        (
        {
        _id: id,
        "UIList.UiName": "ManageRole"
    },
                {
                    $set: {
                        "UIList.$.View": "true",
                        "UIList.$.Edit": "true"
                    }
                },
   function (err, doc) {

        res.json(doc);
    }
    );
```

Comment: This is exactly same as the answer i gave. You should have marked my answer as the correct answer, i gave the solution to the problem you had with your code.

Comment: :@ravi Shankar : i done this query before a day. so that i am not mark as your answer. and you are not mentioned id name in your answer

Answer (score 1):

you should use `$set` instead of  `$push` to change the value of `view` from `false` to `true`.

Try this:

```
newRole.update({ 
    "UIList.UiName": "ManageRole" 
},{ 
    $set: { "UIList.$.View": "true", "UIList.$.Edit": "true" } 
},function (err, doc) {
    res.json(doc);
});
```